# AngularJS ngOptions track by does not set entire object to ngModel

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, ng-options, angularjs-track-by

Here my json object :

```
 $scope.todos = [{
    name: 'angular',
    field: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    id: 1
  }, {
    name: 'asd',
    field: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
    id: 2
  }];
```

I give select as :

```
<select ng-model="dashboard.type" ng-options="item as item.name for item in todos track by item.name"></select>
```

Now when an option is chosen i want another select which iterates upon `ngModel` of previous select. The next   looks like :

```
<select ng-model="dashboard.label" ng-options="item as item for item in dashboard.type.field"></select>
```

It works fine when i choose the option manually but when their is a value in dashboard.type (eg: `$scope.dashboard.type.name = 'qwe'`) in my script, it uses `track by` to choose the option and save it in `dashboard.type`, instead of saving the entire object it just saves the value used in `track by` option.

Value for dashboard.type:

1. when i choose option manually :
   `{"name":"qwe","field":["a","b","c","d","f"],"id":3}`
2. When track by is used :
   `{"name":"qwe"}`

**NOTE:** I cannot use `track by item` . It has to be a property of the object `item`. It can either be `name` or `id`.

Here's a [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ikgA9qk2YqbOFIaz8eZQ?p=preview).

**Edit :**

As pointed out by many, i would like to clarify that I can not initialise the object to any value of `todos` list. This is because `dashboard.type.name` value would be different every single time and `todos` list vary from 10 to 100's of objects. Now I have to iterate the list `todos` check if `todos[index].name==someName` and assign the relevant object. I am actively trying to avoid this soution (because there has to be a better way).

**NOTE :**  I also tried using `ng-change` and assign the actual object to `dashboard.type.name` but that works only when option is selected manually ,which already seems to be working fine. It does not assign the object when `track by` is used.

**IMPORTANT:** `$scope.dashboard.type.name = 'qwe'` is just an example. Value of `$scope.dashboard.type.name` may change every single time the page is loaded.

PS: Also i should have mentioned this earlier.Sorry, My bad!

Comment: just change your initialization like this
$scope.dashboard={};
 $scope.dashboard.type ={}
 $scope.dashboard.type ={
    name: 'qwe',
    field: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f'],
    id: 3
  } ;

Comment: if i could do the last part without iterating through list of `todos` than yeah, it would work. PS : I have updated the question , please check again.

Comment: in that case call a function on ng-init and initialize there based on value you want

Comment: tried it, does not work, can you show me in a fiddle??

Answer (score 1):

This issue is not because of track by. Setting a default value by doing `$scope.dashboard.type.name = 'qwe'`, causes `ng-model` to look like `$scope.dashboard.type = {name : 'qwe'}`. Instead of selecting the default value this way, you should use `$scope.dashboard.type = $scope.todos[2];`. This will make sure the entire object is set to `$scope.dashboard.type`.

[Edited plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/0WJ4vBIqmfE7qvits5cr?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

To initialize the modal by a default value you can use ng-init. For example

```
 <select ng-init="dashboard.type = todos[2]" ng-model="dashboard.type" ng-options="item as item.name for item in todos track by item.name">
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

call this function on ng-init
in html

```
ng-init ="initialize();"
```

in js

```
$scope.dashboard={};//initialize object
$scope.dashboard.type ={}//initialize object

$scope.initialize =function(){


//no need to iterate if it is certain that your Id and index is always same suppose your initial id is 3

//then
var currId =3;//suppose initial id is there
$scope.dashboard.type =$scope.todos[currId]

}
```

here is codepen for it
http://codepen.io/vkvicky-vasudev/pen/MeexmK

Comment: i have just given a random condition in if you can use you own condition

Comment: thanks but here you are using `.forEach()` to loop through the list and set the valid object into `$scope.dashboard.type` as i metioned that this solution works but my question is that : is there better way of doing it other than looping through list ?

Comment: that can done if you know id which is to be selected initially and if it is certain that your id matches array index always, please find the changed code pen